# Wait for firebase to initialize/load

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using the below code in router to secure route for authenticated users only.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

// Other code ...

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some((record) => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  const isAuthenticated = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  if (requiresAuth && !isAuthenticated) {
    next('/login');
  } else if (!requiresAuth && isAuthenticated) {
    next('/dashboard');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Problem is that when page refreshes the `firebase` is undefined right away. I want the firebase object to be initialized/loaded before I load any page or use the `firebase` object. How to do this?

I am using Vue 2 and firebase 9.

Comment: `firebase` is always initialised properly. It's the auth state / current user that takes some time to settle